# Trying to get setState to work synchronously somehow

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to set the state of a variable that is initially populated from an API call...

```
getInServiceVenues = () =>{
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    let bodyInService = [];
    let iterationInService = 0;
    let RequestingNetworkOperatorList = [];
    
    axios.post( '/propertymanagement/listVenues', bodyInService, 
    {
        headers: {}
    })
        .then( response => {
            if (this._isMounted) {
            this.setState({loading: false});
            this.setState({venues: []});
            const venuesInService = response.data.InServiceVenueList;
            let venueIdInService = null;
            let updatedVenuesInService = [];
            bodyInService.push(venuesInService);
            
            bodyInService.forEach(val=>{
                    venueIdInService = Object.keys(bodyInService[0]);
                    //console.log(venueId);
                })
            if(this.state.venuesInService!==[]){
                    this.setState({venuesInService:[]});
                }
            venueIdInService.forEach(val=>{
                
                updatedVenuesInService = bodyInService.map(venueInService => {
                    return {
                        ...venueInService[venueIdInService[iterationInService]],
                        iterationInService,
                        RequestingNetworkOperatorList
                    }

                });
                
                this.setState({
                    venuesInService:[...this.state.venuesInService, updatedVenuesInService]
                });
                iterationInService = iterationInService + 1;
                
            })
        }} )
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            this.setState({error: true});
        });
}
```

On the click of a button I call this function...

```
postSelectedHandler = (venues) => {
    this.setState({newVenue: true}, () => {
        console.log(this.state.newVenue);
    });
    this.getInServiceVenues();
    var event = new Event('input', { bubbles: true });
    this.search_venue.dispatchEvent(event);
    this.filterList(event);
}
```

I can only see the updated state if I were to change an input box's value which is why I have the event variable in my function (trying to do an onChange automatically). Any help would be appreciated.

Edited with the render method attached...

```
render () {
    //console.log(this.state.allVenues);
    const { isBoxVisible } = this.state;
    const {loading } = this.state;
    let inServiceVenues = <Alert variant="danger">Something went wrong!</Alert>;
    let preAuthVenues = <Alert variant="danger">Something went wrong!</Alert>;
    let waitingAuthVenues = <Alert variant="danger">Something went wrong!</Alert>;
    let availableVenues = <Alert variant="danger">Something went wrong!</Alert>;
    if (!this.state.error) {
        inServiceVenues = this.state.filterVenuesInService.map(venueInService => {
            return <Venue 
                key={venueInService[0].iteration} 
                city={venueInService[0].City} 
                VenueName={venueInService[0].VenueName}
                NetworkOperatorID={venueInService[0].NetworkOperatorID}
                ConnectedKeyPools={venueInService[0].connectedKeyPoolList}
                clicked={() => this.postSelectedHandler(venueInService.id)} />;

        });

        preAuthVenues = this.state.filterVenuesPreAuth.map(venuePreAuth => {
            return <PreAuthVenues 
                key={venuePreAuth[0].iteration} 
                city={venuePreAuth[0].City} 
                VenueName={venuePreAuth[0].VenueName}
                NetworkOperatorID={venuePreAuth[0].NetworkOperatorID}
                ConnectedKeyPools={venuePreAuth[0].connectedKeyPoolList}
                clicked={() => this.postSelectedHandler(venuePreAuth.id)} />;

        });

        waitingAuthVenues = this.state.filterVenuesWaiting.map(venueWaitingAuth => {
            //console.log(venueWaitingAuth[0].RequestingNetworkOperatorList[0]);
            let connectedKeyPoolListNewLine;
            
            if(venueWaitingAuth[0].connectedKeyPoolList!=undefined){
                connectedKeyPoolListNewLine = JSON.stringify(venueWaitingAuth[0].connectedKeyPoolList, "<p>").replace(/[[\]"']+/g,'').replace(/,+/g, '\n');
                //console.log(connectedKeyPoolListNewLine.replace(/\n,+/g, ''));
            }else{
                connectedKeyPoolListNewLine = '';
            }
            return <WaitingAuthVenues 
                key={venueWaitingAuth[0].iterationWaitingAuth} 
                city={venueWaitingAuth[0].City} 
                VenueName={venueWaitingAuth[0].VenueName}
                VenueID={venueWaitingAuth[0].awaitingAuthVenueID}
                connectedKeyPoolList={connectedKeyPoolListNewLine}
                RequestedOperatorList={Object.keys(venueWaitingAuth[0].RequestingNetworkOperatorList)}
                AwaitingAuthorizationKeyPool={venueWaitingAuth[0].AwaitingAuthorizationFromKeyPoolOwnerKeyPoolList}
                filteredVenuesInService={inServiceVenues}
                clicked={() => this.postSelectedHandler(venueWaitingAuth.id)} />;

        });
       
        availableVenues = this.state.filterVenuesAvailable.map(venue => {
            let connectedKeyPoolListNewLine;
            
            if(venue[0].connectedKeyPoolList!=undefined){
                connectedKeyPoolListNewLine = JSON.stringify(venue[0].connectedKeyPoolList, "<p>").replace(/[[\]"']+/g,'').replace(/,+/g, '\n');
                //console.log(connectedKeyPoolListNewLine.replace(/\n,+/g, ''));
            }else{
                connectedKeyPoolListNewLine = '';
            }
            //console.log(connectedKeyPoolList);
            return <AvailableVenues 
                key={venue[0].iteration} 
                city={venue[0].City} 
                VenueName={venue[0].VenueName}
                connectedKeyPoolList={connectedKeyPoolListNewLine}
                id={venue[0].availableVenueID}
                clicked={() => this.postSelectedHandler(availableVenues.id)} 
                submitted={this.forceUpdateHandler}
                getNewData={this.getAvailableVenues}/>;

        });
        //console.log(this.state.venues[0]);
        
    }
```

Comment: You should never have to dispatch any event manually in React. Besides that, does your `render` function have a dependency on your component's state's `venuesInService`? If so, any updates to the state should trigger a re-render i.e. you would see the updated state. If you do and it's not working, post your `render` function

Comment: @nbokmans my render method is above now. Thanks!